# Angularjs + Bootstrap + Accordion - Dynamic construction

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create an accordion whose contents is fully dynamic, meaning that the number of "folders" within the accordion may change, as well as the contents of each folder.

The contents of the accordion is determined by an array of objects held within a JSON. Each entity in the array may contain data that requires different layout of the accordion's folders. This includes building contents programmatically and deploying through the use of `$sce.trustAsHtml (MyHTML_Contents)`.

Moreover, the construction of the accordion takes place using `ng-repeat`.

Here are my problems/questions:

1. The html defining the accordion looks like the following:

   ```
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div ng-repeat="One_Item in Items_List track by One_Item.Item_ID">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_{{One_Item.Item_ID}}" href="This_Page/#collapse_{{One_Item.Item_ID}}">
                        {{One_Item.Item_ID}}</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapse_{{One_Item.Item_ID}}">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin:0px 0px 5px -15px">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">For Item-ID {{One_Item.Item_ID}} the related text is {{One_Item.Text}}</label>
                           <!--- Other stuff... -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   ```

   The accordion is created, but the sub-folders are not automatically collapsed (i.e. when clicking at sub-folder X, I expect any other expanded sub-folder to collapse, but it does not).
2. The "body" within each sub-folder includes parts programmatically generated (as mentioned above, using `$sce.trustAsHtml`). To this end, I need to "dynamically" define the name to be assigned to the `ng-bind-html` directive, something like:

   ```
   <div ng-bind-html="This_Subfolder_Contents_{{One_Item.Item_ID}}">
   ```

   Then, the JS assignment would loop like:

   ```
   $scope.This_Subfolder_Contents_1 = $sce.trustAsHtml(MyHTML_Contents) ;
   ```

   where, as stated, `MyHTML_Contents` is built programmatically.

   This triggers an error by Angular (illegal syntax).